# How to specify the map attribute of HTML in a JSF page

Tags: html, dictionary, jsf-2, commandlink, coords

I am trying to replicate the below html page using JSF. But can't find the correct JSF tag to do so.

**HTML content** (Required HTML):

```
<body>
<div class="image">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area shape="circle" id="circle" coords="135,596,34" href="http://www.google.co.in" alt="Circle" />
        <area shape="rect" id="square" coords="192,567,249,628" href="http://www.youtube.com" alt="Square" />
    </map>
</div>
</body>
```

**JSF Page** (JSF to be modified to get above HTML):

```
<body>
<f:view>
<h:outputText value="This is a JSF page"></h:outputText>
<br/>
<h:form>
<h:graphicImage id="image" value="image.jpg" usemap="true">
    <h:commandLink action="#{managedBean.method}" id="links1" value="map1" coords="135,596,34" shape="circle"></h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink action="#{managedBean.method}" id="links2" value="map2" coords="192,567,249,628" shape="rec"></h:commandLink>
</h:graphicImage>
</h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
```

Please suggest the correct JSF format to replicate the above HTML page using the  JSF page and it calls a method of ManagedBean when clicked on the link.

Comment: you should try using the <h:body>, also look into the <ui:composition>

Comment: i am willing to call the managedBean method on onclick of the link, but that way i will not be able to call the methods.
Is there any way so that link is placed using JSF and onclick it calls the method of managedBean

Comment: So you want to invoke a specific method in your bean from the commandLink?

Comment: Yes.
its like links should be present on specific coordinate on a single image and all the link on the image should invoke a specific method.